# Eloquent findOrFail on Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Say that `$post` is a `Post` model in eloquent and it has many `Comment` models related.

Here is the post model:

```php
/**
 * Get comments.
 */
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
}
```

I am trying to retrieve a comment that belongs to the post by its `id`. Running the following code will return the comment if the comment exists, but it does not take into account if it belongs to that post (relationship). This allows users to retrieve comments even if they are not on the current post.

```php
$comment = $post->comments()->findOrFail($commentId);
```

The following returns a collection first and then finds the correct comment by `id`.

```php
$comment = $post->comments->find($commentId);
```

However, I need the `findOrFail()` method via the Query Builder instead of the `find()` method on a collection to return an exception instead of getting an `undefined error` when trying to access a property of the comment.

Comment: It will be quite difficult to say exactly without looking at your relationship model. But, what about replacing that find with `findOrFail`. Does not that work? If not, could you show how you have defined your relationship.

Comment: @SarojShrestha replacing find with findOrFail in the last line returns: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::findOrFail does not exist. I have updated my original post with model definitions.

Comment: `findOrFail()` works for me. Can you log the executed query with `\DB::enableQueryLog(); [...] dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`?

Comment: I suppose `first()` method should be more appropriate if you're intending for only one comment. you can use `->comments()->where('comments.id', $commentId)->first()` How about that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```php
// get Post:
// $post = Post::find($postId);
// get the comment.
$comments = $post->comments()->where('id', $commentId)->get(); // If they are many.
// $comment = $post->comments()->where('id', $commentId)->first(); // If just one.

if (empty($comments)) // 'if($comment)' in case it is just one.
{
    abort(404, 'The comments does not exist.');
}

return view('some.view')->withComments($comments);
```

Then in your view use `$comments`.

---

### Update:

Try this:

```php
$post->load('comments', function ($query) use ($commentId) {
        $query->findOrFail($commentId);
});
```

Then:

```php
return view('some.view')->withComments($post->comments);
```

Comment: This works, but I'd prefer if I could do it all in one line using the findOrFail method.

Comment: @Dynamic I've updated my answer. Don't know if this will work tho, haven't test it yet. Make me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$comment = $post->comments()->findOrFail($commentId);
```

with

```
$comment = \App\Models\Comment::findOrFail($commentId);
```

However, i assume your comment id is unique and does not matter if you pivot through post tables or if you access it directly...

Comment: This would allow me to access a comment that does not belong the particular post model.

Comment: There should be no problem since you already calculated somehow that $commentId... if you still think this can give you access to the wrong comments, you can do something like Comment::where('post_id', $post->id)->findOrFail($commentId)